# PHP - Why does AUTH_TYPE show as undefined in $_SERVER?

Tags: php, http-headers, php-7, authorize

As documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php):

> Once the user has filled in a username and a password, the URL containing the PHP script will be called again with the predefined variables `PHP_AUTH_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_PW`, and `AUTH_TYPE` set to the user name, password and authentication type respectively.

`PHP_AUTH_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_PW` are available. But when I am trying to access the `AUTH_TYPE`:

```
echo $_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE'];
```

Then it says:

```
Undefined index AUTH_TYPE in ...
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) that you linked, states and seems to need to be used with [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), per *"It is possible to use the header() function to send an "Authentication Required"...."* and *"See the header() function for more information."* along with the example(s) shown below that. So when used on its own, is the probable cause as to why it's throwing you an undefined index notice.

Comment: Yes, of course, I am using the `header()` function. but sorry your comment is not stable to understand what you want to say.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The question says it's setting the `PHP_AUTH_xxx` variables, which implies that it already went through the authentication dialog. So it should have set `AUTH_TYPE` as well.

Comment: @Barmar Given what they posted for code, doesn't really help anyone. The post for me is unclear. Maybe you can get something else out of them.

Comment: If the post for you is unclear then do the `Basic` HTTP authentication between client and server once done then try to do `echo $_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE'];` and then share what you get.

Comment: I just reproduced this. I used `print_r($_SERVER);` after authenticating and there's no `AUTH_TYPE` variable.

Comment: I confirmed it with PHP 5.6 and 7.3.

Comment: I think the documentation is just wrong. It also doesn't say that the `PHP_AUTH_xxx` variables are only set when using Basic authentication. Digest authentication sets different variables.

Comment: @Barmar Ok so I appear to have been wrong somewhere and it makes perfect sense when something is unclear (for me). Seeing the thread continue, am starting to understand more as to what's going on. Maybe they (PHP.net) should be informed of this then.

Comment: Yes either documentation is wrong or may be php developers forgot to populate the AUTH_TYPE internally while HTTP Basic authentication is performed.